# Does memory leak in a while loop when the same pointer is reinitialized

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

Does this cause a memory leakage?

```
while(true){
  std::string* items = new std::string[size];
  if (SOME_CONDITION){
      //do something
  }
}
delete[] items;
```

The while loop may iterate over hundreds of times but the same pointer is resized so I think it shouldn't cause a memory leakage.

Comment: Yes, there is a memory leak.   In each loop iteration, a `std::string` is dynamically allocated, and never released.    Also (assuming all that code is in a function) the `items` referred to in `delete [] items`  is not the same `items` as the one defined in the loop body, so does not affect it.   If the code compiles at all, there must be a previous definition of something named `items` AND the `delete [] items` STILL will not affect the `items` within the loop body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this will cause a memory leak. If you call `new[]` twice, you will allocate two chunks of memory. If you call `delete[]` once, you will only free one of them.

I don't know what you mean by "same pointer is resized" exactly. Nothing is resized in this loop, it just allocates a new block of memory each iteration.

Here's a simple fix:

```
std::string* items = nullptr;
while(true){
  delete[] items;
  items = new std::string[size];
  if (SOME_CONDITION){
      //do something
  }
}
delete[] items;
```

The more traditional way to do this is like this:

```
while(true){
  std::string* items = new std::string[size];
  if (SOME_CONDITION){
      //do something
  }
  delete[] items;
}
```

Even better would be to use something other than `new` such as `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: by resized I mean the same block of memory that was allocated was resized instead of creating a new block of memory, well you cleared my doubt so I'm gonna accept this answer in a couple of minutes

Comment: The `new[]`/`delete[]` interface doesn't support resizing. You'd have to use `malloc`/`free` (which supports `realloc`) for that. But that won't work for C++ objects -- you can't just move an object to another area of memory because that can corrupt the object.

Comment: The best way to handle this is to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`